# Pseudo R^2 from Regression Quantiles for panel data

Tags: r, quantile

I am using the "rqpd" package to run the following panel data of quantile regression in R:

```
library(rqpd)
data(bwd)
cre.form1 <- dbirwt ~ smoke + dmage + agesq + novisit + pretri2 + 
pretri3 | momid3 |smoke
crem.fit1 <- rqpd(cre.form1, panel(method="cre", taus <- c(0.9)),data=bwd)
```

the rqpd package form [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1082&fbclid=IwAR33Yzu4PBvDSfHDk9Vuz2nTJ1GoQPMs86w2Mmoq6UuHTLSypyGMfL-N_hw)

I can get the result via

```
summary(crem.fit1)
```

However, I would like to know the Pseudo R2 (goodness of fit) - which the summary command seems to deliver for OLS regressions, but not in case of panel data in quantile regressions.
Does anybody know, how to extract the Pseudo R2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `rqpd` package. In General the pR^2 is:

> 1 - deviance/null.deviance

I am using a the standard logistic regression example:

```
utils::data(anorexia, package = "MASS")
anorex.1 <- glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt),
                family = gaussian, data = anorexia)
```

When I calculate the pR^2, I am using:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
anorex.1 %>% glance() %>%
  mutate(pR2 = 1 - deviance/null.deviance)
```

Output would be:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 8
  null.deviance df.null logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual   pR2
          <dbl>   <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <dbl>
1         4525.      71  -240.  490.  501.    3311.          68 0.268
```

pR^2 would be 0.268. Hope that helps.